# ADAL JavaScript support for on premise ADFS (ADAL JS)

Tags: adal

How can you configure ADAL JS to use an on-premise Active Directory (Windows Server 2012 R2, ADFS)? The announcement post (http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/) and samples on GitHub (https://github.com/AzureADSamples) do not specifically address this. Or is that not a supported scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is currently not supported. ADFS does not support the oauth2 implicit grant, which is at the heart of the scenario

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Vittorio. Any plans to add support for that grant to ADFS? Was trying to write a SPA that could auth against on-prem or Azure AD with minimal differences in the code path. Any suggestions?

Comment: For anybody watching, do to some of these limitations, we ended up ditching ADAL for on-premise and rolling something on our own.

Comment: I am a little confused. @vibronet, according to your blog this IS supported: "Support for Windows Server 2012 R2 ADFS On-Premises for OAuth2 flows. As mentioned this is not really a new feature, but now we can finally talk about it! Smile If you want to play with it, you can easily adapt http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/07/30/securing-a-web-api-with-windows-server-2012-r2-adfs-and-katana/  to use ADAL .NET instead of a Windows Store client." 

You posted that Aug 2, 2013 (before this SO answer). So, is it or is it not possible to use ADAL with On Premise ADFS (3.0)? So lost right now...

Comment: There are many OAuth2 grants. The one used by Adal JS is not supported by ADFS. ADFS supports only the authorization code grant for public clients. Adal Js requires the implicit grant.

Comment: @vibronet so your talking code flow without client secret?

Comment: No, I meant the implicit grant :) but now it is available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

With ADFS 4.0 and Windows Server 2016 this is now possible, you can use adal.js as is for authentication of users on on-premise ADFS